# Remove opacity from carousel images in Materialize design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I am using 3d carousel. And images have some opacity. But i don't want opacity on images.

```js
    $('.carousel').carousel({
            dist:0,
            shift:0,
            padding:20, 
           interval:100
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


 <div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>


    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>

</div>
```

I want to reduce opacity from all images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option for the carousel plugin to set the opacity on the images, so you would have to make it happen via css styles. Not the best choice, but I don't see any simpler way :)

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  dist: 0,
  shift: 0,
  padding: 20,
  interval: 100
});
```

```css
.carousel .carousel-item {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="carousel">
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1">
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2">
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3">
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4">
  </a>


  <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to help. If my question use full for others then voting up. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First answer, making it:

```
.carousel .carousel-item {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

did not work for me as I had a requirement to show 3 Images in the carousel without any opacity.

Second answer, was difficult to understand and tweak further.

My solution: Using `MutationObserver`, listen/observe for attribute changes on `.carousel` parent div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.carousel').carousel({
        'numVisible': 3
    });

    var targetNode = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel")[0];

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
        // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
        for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
            }
            else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
                console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
            }
            displayTopThreeImages();
        }
    };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);

    function displayTopThreeImages() {
        [...document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-item")].forEach(item=>{item.style.opacity = item.style.opacity > 0 ? 1 : item.style.opacity});
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution above removes all of the opacity transition including the transition of the last item on the left and the last item on the right. I didn't like it how it was looking, so I went through the code of Materialize Carousel, and finally come up with this solution changing the _scroll function using prototype, hope this helps someone, just place this code before you initialize the  Carousel:

```
M.Carousel.prototype._scroll = function(x) {
// Track scrolling state
if (!this.$el.hasClass('scrolling')) {
    this.el.classList.add('scrolling');
}
if (this.scrollingTimeout != null) {
    window.clearTimeout(this.scrollingTimeout);
}
this.scrollingTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.$el.removeClass('scrolling');
}, this.options.duration);

// Start actual scroll
let i,
    half,
    delta,
    dir,
    tween,
    el,
    elLastLeft,
    elLastRight,
    alignment,
    zTranslation,
    tweenedOpacity,
    centerTweenedOpacity;
let lastCenter = this.center;
let numVisibleOffset = 1 / this.options.numVisible;

this.offset = typeof x === 'number' ? x : this.offset;
this.center = Math.floor((this.offset + this.dim / 2) / this.dim);
delta = this.offset - this.center * this.dim;
dir = delta < 0 ? 1 : -1;
tween = -dir * delta * 2 / this.dim;
half = this.count >> 1;

if (this.options.fullWidth) {
    alignment = 'translateX(0)';
    centerTweenedOpacity = 1;
} else {
    alignment = 'translateX(' + (this.el.clientWidth - this.itemWidth) / 2 + 'px) ';
    alignment += 'translateY(' + (this.el.clientHeight - this.itemHeight) / 2 + 'px)';
    centerTweenedOpacity = 1 - numVisibleOffset * tween;
}

// Set indicator active
if (this.showIndicators) {
    let diff = this.center % this.count;
    let activeIndicator = this.$indicators.find('.indicator-item.active');
    if (activeIndicator.index() !== diff) {
      activeIndicator.removeClass('active');
      this.$indicators
        .find('.indicator-item')
        .eq(diff)[0]
        .classList.add('active');
    }
}

// center
// Don't show wrapped items.
if (!this.noWrap || (this.center >= 0 && this.center < this.count)) {
    el = this.images[this._wrap(this.center)];
    elLastLeft = this.images[this._wrap(this.center - half)];
    elLastRight = this.images[this._wrap(this.center + half)];

    // Add active class to center item.
    if (!$(el).hasClass('active')) {
      this.$el.find('.carousel-item').removeClass('active');
      el.classList.add('active');
    }
    let transformString = `${alignment} translateX(${-delta / 2}px) translateX(${dir *
      this.options.shift *
      tween *
      i}px) translateZ(${this.options.dist * tween}px)`;
    this._updateItemStyle(el, centerTweenedOpacity, 0, transformString);
}

for (i = 1; i <= half; ++i) {
    // right side
    if (this.options.fullWidth) {
      zTranslation = this.options.dist;
      tweenedOpacity = i === half && delta < 0 ? 1 - tween : 1;
    } else {
      zTranslation = this.options.dist * (i * 2 + tween * dir);
      // Amend the tweenedOpacity
      tweenedOpacity = (1 * (1 * 2 + tween * -dir )) -1;
      tweenedOpacity = parseFloat(tweenedOpacity.toFixed(2));
    }
    // Don't show wrapped items.
    if (!this.noWrap || this.center + i < this.count) {
        el = this.images[this._wrap(this.center + i)];
        let transformString = `${alignment} translateX(${this.options.shift +
            (this.dim * i - delta) / 2}px) translateZ(${zTranslation}px)`;
        // Only give Opacity Transition to last item 
        if (i == half ) {
            this._updateItemStyle(el, tweenedOpacity, -i, transformString);
        }
        else {
            this._updateItemStyle(el, centerTweenedOpacity, -i, transformString);
        }
    }

    // left side
    if (this.options.fullWidth) {
      zTranslation = this.options.dist;
      tweenedOpacity = i === half && delta > 0 ? 1 - tween : 1;
    } else {
      zTranslation = this.options.dist * (i * 2 - tween * dir);
      // Amend the tweenedOpacity
      tweenedOpacity = (1 * (1 * 2 - tween * -dir )) -1;
      tweenedOpacity = parseFloat(tweenedOpacity.toFixed(2));           
    }

    // Don't show wrapped items.
    if (!this.noWrap || this.center - i >= 0) {
        el = this.images[this._wrap(this.center - i)];
        let transformString = `${alignment} translateX(${-this.options.shift +
            (-this.dim * i - delta) / 2}px) translateZ(${zTranslation}px)`;
        // Only give Opacity Transition to last item
        if (i == half ) {    
            this._updateItemStyle(el, tweenedOpacity, -i, transformString);
        }
        else {
            this._updateItemStyle(el, centerTweenedOpacity, -i, transformString);
        }
    }
}

// center
// Don't show wrapped items.
if (!this.noWrap || (this.center >= 0 && this.center < this.count)) {
    el = this.images[this._wrap(this.center)];
    let transformString = `${alignment} translateX(${-delta / 2}px) translateX(${dir *
      this.options.shift *
      tween}px) translateZ(${this.options.dist * tween}px)`;
    this._updateItemStyle(el, centerTweenedOpacity, 0, transformString);
}

// onCycleTo callback
let $currItem = this.$el.find('.carousel-item').eq(this._wrap(this.center));
if (lastCenter !== this.center && typeof this.options.onCycleTo === 'function') {
    this.options.onCycleTo.call(this, $currItem[0], this.dragged);
}

// One time callback
if (typeof this.oneTimeCallback === 'function') {
    this.oneTimeCallback.call(this, $currItem[0], this.dragged);
    this.oneTimeCallback = null;
}
};

// Here you init the carousel ...
```